# How does #define work with function pointers?

Tags: c, macros, return-value, function-call

Please see the below code :

```
SomeStructure* SomeFunc();
#define kkData (*SomeFunc())
```

Question : What does `kkData` represents ?

EDIT : Removed semi-colon from second line.

Comment: `kkData` represents what is written in front of it, meaning `(*SomeFunc());`. preprocessor just replace it.

Comment: There are no function pointers shown there. `kkData` calls `SomeFunc` and dereferences the return value.

Comment: @kaylum  (*SomeFunc()) ---> function pointer notation

Comment: No it's not. As I said, `SomeFunc()` is just calling the function. And `*` dereferences the return value.

Comment: One thing to remember is that `kkData` does not represent *anything* as far as the compiler is concerned. The compiler will never get to see any `kkData`, because the *preprocessor* will have replaced all occurrences of `kkData` with the verbatim string `(*SomeFunc())` -- the meaning of which will be depending on context. This holds true for *any* `#define`. (And the issue becomes painfully obvious when you want to step-debug a more complex macro).

Comment: It depends on the context in which the macro is used. You could do `void func(SomeStructure* kkdata)` and then it's not a function call but a strange parameter declaration of a function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This directive

```
#define kkData (*SomeFunc());
```

means a call of the function `SomeFunc` and dereferencing the pointer to a structure returned from the function.

For example you could write in the program

```
SomeStructure s = kkData
```

Pay attention to that the semicolon in the directive should be removed. In this case the code in the program

```
SomeStructure s = kkData;
```

will be more clear.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the semi-colon from the second line.

Comment: It could as well be used as `void func(SomeStructure* kkdata);` and then it has a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As with all `#define` directives `kkData` is simply a token that will be replaced by `(*SomeFunc())` before compilation. It is not by any means a function pointer, just a macro used to get a result from `SomeFunc()` and dereference it, in a single word.

Comment: Note that macro replacement operates as preprocessor token replacement, not text replacement. If it were mere text replacement, it could close strings, join identifiers, merge `+` and `+` into `++`, and so on. E.g., after `#define x -3`, the code `y = 4-x;` would be equivalent to `y = 4 -- x;` rather than `y = 4 - -x;`, and the former would cause an error. These changes do not happen because the source code has been tokenized before macro replacement is performed.